# NIntegrate with singularities, exclusions, etc

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following expression needs to be numerically (or analytically) integrated between limits 0, 2$\pi$

```
fnD = 1/(c*Sin[x] + d*Cos[x] + D)
```

The following attempts were made, most likely with some error in the input, but I don't know exactly where.

```
nfnDin = NIntegrate[fnD, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Exclusions -> {D == (-d)*Cos[x] - c*Sin[x]}]
```

which gives

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Boole[Re[D+d Cos[x]+c Sin[x]]>0]/(D+d Cos[x]+c Sin[x]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,6.28319}}.
```

Try `Block[{x = Pi/2, c = 0, d = 0}, NIntegrate[fnD, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]]`

which yields

```
Block::dup: Duplicate local variable x found in local variable specification {x=0,x=\[Pi]/2,c=0,d=0}.
```

Try

```
Block[{x = 0, x = Pi/2, c = 0, d = 0}, NIntegrate[fnD, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]]
```

which yields

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 1/D has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,6.28319}}.
```

and

`NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 1/(D+d Cos[x]+c Sin[x]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,6.28319}}.`

How about

```
Integrate[fnD, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Exclusions -> {x == 0, x == Pi/2}]
```

but this is also not OK because the output is

```
Integrate::optx: Unknown option Exclusions in Integrate[1/(d+D),{0,0,2 \[Pi]},Exclusions->{True,False}].
```

Where is the error in input? Assume that the variables involved are all Real.

Comment: It is good practice to have your symbol names started with an undercase letter. You use the symbol `D`, which is the Mathematica name for differentiaton, so that cannot be used as a variable.

Comment: Where did you define parameter `D`?

Comment: Works for me:`Block[{x = Pi/2, c = 0, d = 0, d1 = 1}, 
 NIntegrate[1/(d1 + d Cos[x] + c Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2*Pi}]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
        fnD := 1/(c*Sin[x] + d*Cos[x] + k);
        nfnDin = Integrate[fnD, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
     (* output*)
       (*-((2 Sqrt[-((d - k)^2/(c^2 + d^2 - k^2))] \[Pi])/(d - k))*)
```